# ASP.NET Core Web API - Error CS1955 Non-invocable member 'File' cannot be used like a method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In my ASP.NET Core-6 Web API, I want to download file based on parameter id.

So, I have this repository that will eventually be called in the controller:

Repository:

```
public async Task<string> GetLeaveDocumentByIdAsync(Guid id)
{
    var leaveAttachment = _dbContext.LeaveApplications
        .Include(la => la.LeaveApproval)
        .ThenInclude(la => la.LeaveApprovalAttachments)
        .Where(la => (bool)la.IsApproved)
        .SelectMany(la => la.LeaveApproval.LeaveApprovalAttachments)
        .FirstOrDefault(laa => laa.Id == id);
    var filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), leaveAttachment.FilePath);
    var memory = new MemoryStream();
    using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
    {
        await stream.CopyToAsync(memory);
    }
    memory.Position = 0;
    var contentType = "APPLICATION/octet-stream";
    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
    return File(memory, contentType, fileName);
}
```

Service:

```
public async Task<Response<string>> GetLeaveDocumentServiceByIdAsync(Guid id)
{
    var response = new Response<string>();
    var leave = await _unitOfWork.Leaves.GetLeaveDocumentByIdAsync(id);
    if (leave != null)
    {
        response.Message = "File Downloaded Successfully";
        response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
        response.Successful = true;
    }
    else
    {
        response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        response.Successful = false;
        response.Message = $"File Download Failed. Please try again";
        return response;
    }
    return response;
}
```

Controller:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<Response<string>>> DownloadLeaveDocumentAsync(Guid id)
{
    var result = await _leaveApprovalsService.GetLeaveDocumentServiceByIdAsync(id);
    return StatusCode(result.StatusCode, result);
}
```

This is the flow:

```
Repository -> Service -> Controller
```

I want to download the selected file by id, but I got this error in the Repository:

> Error CS1955  Non-invocable member 'File' cannot be used like a method.

**File** is highlighted in

```
return File(memory, contentType, fileName)
```

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: What do you expect `File(memory, contentType, fileName)` to do? Is it a method you expect to return a `string`? (After all, your method returns `Task<string>`.) Where is the method you're expecting to call defined?

Comment: `return File()` only works inside a `PageModel`.